# CakePhp : Find/Paginate with conditions on "hasMany" assiociated models

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i'm trying to make a litle search action for one of my Model.
My Model `Salarie` was associated with some other models, in particular :

- `Salarie` -> hasMany -> `Permission`
- `Salarie` -> hasOne -> `Carburant`

So i try to make a find() on my Model `Salarie` to select records that match a keyword.
This keyword can by found in my model `Salarie`, or in associated model `Permission`, `Carburant`.

Here is my actual find() :

```
    $salaries = $this->Salarie->find('all',array(
        'contain' => array(
            'User','Agence','Entitee','Fonction','Contact','Ligne','Car','CallingCard','Badge','Carburant','Permission'),
        'conditions'=>array(
            'OR'=>array(
                'Salarie.nom LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
                'Salarie.prenom LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
                'Salarie.secu LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
                'Salarie.tel LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
                'Salarie.mobile LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
                'Salarie.ville LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
                'Salarie.email LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
                'Carburant.numero LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',
            )
        )
    ));
```

This code works but doesn't looks into `Permission` table/model, if i add this line
`'Permission.login LIKE' => '%'.$keyWord.'%',` in my conditions array i got a error

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Permission.login' in 'where clause'`

I've try with `contain` but it's not what i looking for, `contain` filters datas into the results of the `find`.

if someone got a tips ?

Comment: Verify your associations with the `Permission` in the `Salarie` Model. Because the others associations seems to work, a bad declaration of the `Permission` can be the problem.

Comment: i've check my associations but it's only append on hasMany link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL joins are only done by hasOne and belongsTo associations, not for hasMany and HABTM. You can use [Linkable](https://github.com/lorenzo/linkable) plugin to filter records based on conditions for hasMany associations.

Comment: OK, i will take a look this night.

Comment: So i have take a look to Linkable, but no doc and no clear example are provided. So i don't see any way to use it in my code.

Comment: Well the readme does have usage examples plus there are [tests](https://github.com/lorenzo/linkable/blob/master/Test/Case/Model/Behavior/LinkableBehaviorTest.php) which show various usages.

Answer (score 0):

i've found something that solve my problem.

```
     'group' => 'Salarie.nom',
         'joins'=>array(
             array(
                'table'=>'permissions',
                'alias'=>'Permission',
                'type'=>'LEFT',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'Salarie.id = Permission.salarie_id',
                )
            )
        )
```

if i had this code to my find the SQL query works great. I just have to `GROUP BY` to avoid double result.